# Is a Singleton HttpClient receiving a new HttpMessageHandler After X Minutes

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, httpclient, httpclientfactory

I register my HttpClient in the Factory:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ICatalogService, CatalogService>()
    .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

This ICatalogService is injected via constructor in a Singleton Service.

Will I receive after 2 Minutes internally a new HttpMessageHandler or only if ICatalogService would be injected in NOT a Singleton Service after 2 Minutes?

Basically, does the internal HttpMessageHandler expires also when the wrapping HttpHandler
is used as a Singleton?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does the internal HttpMessageHandler expires also when the wrapping HttpHandler is used as a Singleton?

**WARNING: Keeping `HttpClient` instances alive through Singletons is *not* safe.**

The configured `HttpMessageHandler` instance will expire after two minutes. Any `HttpClient` that is created *after* the the expiry date will get a new `HttpMessageHandler` containing a new expiry date. But this doesn't help a `HttpClient` instance that is kept alive.

**IMPORTANT:** `HttpClient` will keep using the same `HttpMessageHandler` for as long as it lives and will, therefore,
[not respect DNS changes](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18348). Only new `HttpMessageHandler` instances will see DNS updates.

This means that as long as you keep the `HttpClient` alive, that `HttpClient` will miss DNS changes, which is why `HttpClient` instances should only live for a short period of time. Creating and cleaning up `HttpClient` instances is very cheap as long as you reuse the underlying `HttpMessageHandler` instances (which is what the infrastructure does for you).

In your case, unfortunately, your `HttpClient` is injected into the `CatalogService`, which is injected into a `Singleton` consumer. The `Singleton` keeps the `CatalogService` alive and, therefore, indirectly keeps the `HttpClient` alive for the duration of the application—Your `HttpClient` is now a [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

What you're experiencing is an unfortunate design flaw in the new .NET Core `IHttpClientFactory` infrastructure. I consider this a flaw because IMO the infrastructure should prevent you from holding `HttpClient` instances captive, e.g. by registering the client (your `CatalogService`) as `Scoped`. I [reported this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36067) back in January 2019. Microsoft has acknowledged the problem but has, as of this writing, no solution available.

As there is no solution yet, you have to be very careful not to cause `HttpClient` to be kept alive as Captive Dependency. This means you can't inject it into `Singleton` consumers (even indirect one's).

A good way to prevent this is by registering the client (your `CatalogService`) as `Scoped`. This allows the framework's configuration system to validate whether it is injected into a `Singleton`. But since there is no direct support for this, you will have to make this registration manually, by using the following extension method for instance:

```cs
public static IHttpClientBuilder AddTypedClientScoped<TClient>(
  this IHttpClientBuilder builder)
  where TClient : class
{
    ...
    builder.Services.AddScoped<TClient>(s =>
    {
        var httpClientFactory = s.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(builder.Name);
        var factory = s.GetRequiredService<ITypedHttpClientFactory<TClient>>();
        return factory.CreateClient(httpClient);
    });

    return builder;
}
```

While starting an ASP.NET Core website [while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64061823/264697), the framework will validate scopes for you, which causes an exception when the client is injected into a singleton.

But please be warned that the use this extension method doesn't detect all captive `HttpClient` instances. That's because there are places in ASP.NET Core where components are registered as `Transient` will still being kept alive for the duration of the application. One such case is [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services). The `AddHostedService` extension method is such example. Hosted services are registered as `Transient` while being kept alive as `Singleton`. In my optinion another design flaw. But that means that you should be careful while directly or indirectly injecting `HttpClient` instances into hosted services.

Answer (score -1):

> Will I receive after 2 Minutes internally a new HttpMessageHandler or only if ICatalogService would be injected in NOT a Singleton Service after 2 Minutes?

After each 2 minutes, the old `HttpMessageHandler` will be discard, and the new one doesn't get re-generate right after that but the moment your `HttpClient` make a request.

> Basically, does the internal HttpMessageHandler expires also when the wrapping HttpHandler is used as a Singleton?

I'm not sure how are you going to wrap the handler, since it has to be inherited from `DelegatingHandler` ?
If it's gonna be like `services.AddSingleton<SomeDelegatingHandler>();` then just simply don't do it

But your 2 lines of code was pretty awkward in your use case actually... and here's why

`services.AddHttpClient<ICatalogService, CatalogService>()` will inject HttpClient directly to your `CatalogService`, and also register your `CatalogService` as `Transient`. Therefore, why inject a transient service in a singleton instance ? It's pretty confuse to me.

Comment: Hi Gordon, although you are technically correct in saying that the old `HttpMessageHandler` will be discarded after two minutes, this will only cause newly created `HttpClient` instances to get a fresh `HttpMessageHandler`. Any existing `HttpClient`, unfortunately, will keep its reference to its original `HttpMessageHandler`. This means that long-living `HttpClient` instances will not respect those expirations. In the question, the `HttpClient` of `CatalogService` is kept alive by a Singleton, which can cause problems in the long run. See my answer for more details.

Comment: I have read through your explanation and i actually miss-out the reference pointing part. Thanks for enlighten me @Steven